# Linear Algebra Simple Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hello, I was wondering, in problem #1, does the Ta represent the transformation of A back onto A. I’m doing transformations right now and have gotten decent at them. But the wording is really throwing me off. If I can figure out Ta I believe I can solve it. Normally I see stuff in the textbook like T(x) and I know how to solve, so the wording of this one is throwing me off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is $3\times 4$ matrix. Thus, the linear transformation $\textsf{T}_A:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by $\textsf{T}_A(x)=Ax$, where $x$ is a $4\times 1$ matrix, that is, a column vector.

Comment: So are we able to figure out what the 4×1 matrix is, or is this just asking for us to think whether it is one-to-one & onto?

Comment: The second one. Your welcome!